# Hourly dataset of last 30 days of Bitcoin marketcaps

Tags: data-request

I have got the days wise data from the https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20171228&end=20180127

But for my algorithm, I am in need of the hourly dataset of the coinmarketcaps like historic data. I mean, I need the dataset in the form of the following:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Market Cap
```

But the dataset should be hourly.

Kindly, let me know where I can find such dataset.

Answer (score 0):

### This was temporarily  deleted because I've realized too late that this Q is about marketcaps not prices. However  Marketcap = (price * number of bitcoins in circulation)  so I've undeleted this post.

Bitinfocharts.com provide a [directory](http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv) with numerous compressed gz files with historic data from various trading platforms.

There are many datasets, even from MountGox days apparently. 
However, I have only looked at this file: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/krakenEUR.csv.gz.

This 115MB zipfile is 615 MB uncompressed. It contains a dataset from the Kraken Platform, the series starts in 2014. At this time the table structure looks like this:

```
Observations: 15,386,405
Variables: 3
$ unixtime <int> 1389173189, 1389173198, 1389173198, 1389173265, 1389173339, 1389173528, 1389173534, ...
$ price    <dbl> 624.0, 624.0, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, 623.5, ...
$ amount   <dbl> 0.20000, 0.09767, 0.01358, 0.14896, 0.20000, 0.17630, 0.40633, 0.20000, 1.80000, 0.3...
```

It has a periodicity of 1-10 seconds. You probably can apply your own window function to aggregate up to 1 hour periodicity.

I have done this and it looks like this (pink dots are hourly median prices):

[image]

To get marketcap you can download the number of bitcoins in circulation from Quandl.com: https://www.quandl.com/data/BCHAIN/TOTBC-Total-Bitcoins

The number of Bitcoins in circulation is also well known. Every 10 minutes one block containing (at this time) 12.5 Bitcoins is added tothe blockchain.

The R code I've used to generate this plot:

```
   library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
# setwd("~/code/git/_my/R_stuff/R_diverse")

# days back in humanreadable form, e.g. "2017-12-28"
n <- 30
days_back      <- today() - days(n)

btc_kraken_url <- "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/krakenEUR.csv.gz"
btc_kraken_gz <- basename(btc_kraken_url)
btc_kraken_csv <- str_replace(btc_kraken_gz, "\\.gz$", "")
if(!file.exists(btc_kraken_gz) && !file.exists(btc_kraken_csv)){
        download.file(btc_kraken, destfile = btc_hist)
        system(sprintf("gunzip %s", btc_kraken_gz))
} else if(!file.exists(btc_kraken_csv)){
        system(sprintf("gunzip %s", btc_kraken_gz))
}
csv0 <- read_csv(
  btc_kraken_csv,
  col_names = c("unixtime", "price", "amount")
)
glimpse(csv0)
# grab
csv0 <- csv0 %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(unixtime, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  arrange(unixtime, price) %>%
  select(datetime, price, amount)

summary(csv0)

csv0 <- csv0 %>%
  filter(datetime >= days_back)

# Periodicity
csvz <- xts::as.xts(csv0[,2], order.by=csv0$datetime, unique = FALSE)
xts::periodicity(csvz)

csv <- csv0 %>%
        mutate(datetime = floor_date(datetime, unit = "hour"),
               price = as.integer(price))


csv2 <- csv %>%
        group_by(datetime, price) %>%
        summarize(sum_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
        select(-sum_amount) %>%
        group_by(datetime) %>%
        summarize(median_price = median(price)) %>%
        ungroup()

csv2 <- csv2 %>%
        mutate(datetime =  datetime + lubridate::minutes("30")) %>%
        arrange(datetime)
head(csv2)

myplot <- ggplot(csv0, aes(datetime, price)) +
        geom_line(size=0.1) +
        geom_point(data = csv2,
                   aes(datetime, median_price),
                   color="hotpink", size=0.1) +
        ggtitle("Bitcoin prices on kraken.com, per-Second and Hourly",
                subtitle = sprintf("Bitcoin in Euro, from %s to %s \nsource: %s",
                                   days_back, today(), btc_kraken_url)) +
        ylab("BTC/€")

ggsave(plot = myplot,
       filename =sprintf("bitcoin--%s--%s.png", days_back, today()))
```